# How do you split a list of Size N, into K groups as evenly as possible

Tags: python, algorithm, divide

Similar questions have been asked before, but they answer the question "how to split a list into evenly sized chunks", not split a list into k groups, as evenly sized as possible:

Here is what I want to do:

For example For N = 4, and K = 3: 
Return 3 lists, with the following elements from N 
k1 = N<sub>1</sub> 
k2 = N<sub>2</sub> 
k3 = N<sub>3</sub>, N<sub>4</sub>

or N = 6, and K=4:
Return 4 lists, with the following elements from N 
k1 = N<sub>1</sub> 
k2 = N<sub>2</sub> 
k3 = N<sub>3</sub>, N<sub>4</sub> 
k4 = N<sub>5</sub>, N<sub>6</sub>

In python this can be represented as:

```
n = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
k = 4
print(solution(n,k))
$ ["1"]
$ ["2"]
$ ["3", "4"]
$ ["5", "6"]
```

An example is  saying I have K=4 Processors and N = 6, tasks how do I evenly divide the tasks amongst the processors.

Here is a similar question written in C: [How to share work roughly evenly between processes in MPI despite the array_size not being cleanly divisible by the number of processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658145/how-to-share-work-roughly-evenly-between-processes-in-mpi-despite-the-array-size)

The approach taken there is assign int(N/K) task across the "processors", and share the remainder.

I am wondering if there is a pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43106405/4001592) in particular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [numpy.array_split](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html):

```py
import numpy as np 

arr = range(6) 
np.array_split(arr, 4) 

>>[array([0, 1]), array([2, 3]), array([4]), array([5])]
```